# Installing Inno Setup generated setup as Admin and Non-admin

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have an Inno Setup generated setup that has two separate EXE's (eg: `A.exe` and `B.exe`) bundled on to it.

`A.exe` or `B.exe` is identified via command line argument and executed. Only one application will be installed at a time.

**A.exe -> can only be run by Admin.**

**B.exe -> any user can run**

If, a non-admin user tries to install `A.exe`, which requires admin privileges, I want to automatically detect that and run `B.exe` which is designed for Non-admin users.

So far in the code I've used `PrivilegesRequired=admin`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you ask for, but I've tried to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`IsAdmin` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_isadmin) (or [`IsAdminInstallMode`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_isadmininstallmode) or `IsAdminLoggedOn` [in older versions]) to detect, if the installer is running with elevated privileges or not.